# Yii2: $model->load() returns false

Tags: php, yii2

I have a form where user can load the image. In my controller I have an action called *actionUpdate* which contains code like this.
**Controller**

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    $id = Yii::$app->user->id;
    $model = Page::find()->where(['user_id'=>$id])->one();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'thumbnail');
        $model->thumbnail = $model->url.".".$image->extension;

        if ($model->validate() && $model->save())
        {
            $model->upload();
            //page/url is for the user's page
            return $this->redirect('page/'.$model->url);
        } 
    } 
    else 
    {
        //'update' is a view file with form
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I'm submitting the form, I'm being redirected to the same update action url but with blank screen, instead of redirecting to the user's page. Maybe the problem is in my Model's upload function?

**Model**

```
public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = Page::find()->where(["user_id" => Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
        $this->thumbnail->saveAs('avatars/'.$user->url.'.'.$this->thumbnail->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

could  be, also,  that your validation or save don't return true

```
    if ($model->validate() && $model->save())
    {
        $model->upload();
        //page/url is for the user's page
        return $this->redirect('page/'.$model->url);
    }  else {

        var_dump('not  validated or not saved ')
    }
```

Comment: as usual  ... check for validate  or validation rules ..  once you have clear the error  you can correct it  ..

Comment: Actually, if you put `return $this->render('update', [             'model' => $model,         ]);` instead of the `var_dump` the validation errors will be shown in your form

Comment: @gmc now it shows that the error is 'the file is not chosen' but it is

Answer (score 1):

Please have exception handling (try, catch) in your Model. Never write Model without exception handling.

configure yii_logger db in your machine (you can find it Yii2 docs).

then run

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(log_time, '%Y-%m-%d') log_date, y.*  FROM yii_logger y where level = 1 order by log_time desc limit 20;
```

you may see error backtrace if your code is breaking somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Update code in your actionUpdate

```
$model->upload($image);
```

and in your model upload function

```
public function upload($image)
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = Page::find()->where(["user_id" => Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
        // updated with parameter here
        $image->saveAs('avatars/'.$user->url.'.'.$image->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please update this in your code and check it.

Comment: You know, the thing is that when I'm removing this line
 `$model->thumbnail = $model->url.".".$image->extension;`
everything works correctly. I don't think that problem is in user. But I've updated it and it still the same. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I updated my answered please check it once. as per my understanding upload function is throwing error. Because of thumbnail is not object.

Comment: No, it doesn't help

Comment: What do you mean by thumbnail isn's an object? When I use var_dump it shows `object(yii\web\UploadedFile)#136 (5) { ["name"]=> string(15) "3jg-IZBetys.jpg" ["tempName"]=> string(39) "D:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\phpF546.tmp" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["size"]=> int(14692) ["error"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: $model->thumbnail = $model->url.".".$image->extension; you are assigning file name to thumbnail in your action update but you are trying to access in your model upload function like object of UploadFile class.  $this->thumbnail->saveAs('avatars/'.$user->url.'.'.$this->thumbnail->extension);

Comment: So, how can I avoid it? I need to save a `thumbnail` value in my table as user->url . image->extension